# Swagger API Annotation for Java using Enum as options which break request

Tags: java, enums, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a class defined called **Website Locale** which lits all supported locales for my site

```
public enum WebsiteLocale {

    AU      ("au",      5, "en", "AUD"),    // Australia
    CA      ("ca",      6, "en", "CAD"),    // Canada
    DE      ("de",      1, "de", "EUR"),    // Germany
    ES      ("es",      1, "es", "EUR"),    // Spain
    ES_US   ("es-us",   2, "es", "USD"),    // USA, Spanish language
    EU      ("eu",      4, "en", "EUR"),    // Europe: English and Euros
    FR      ("fr",      1, "fr", "EUR"),    // France
    FR_US   ("fr-us",   2, "fr", "USD"),    // USA, French language
    IT      ("it",      1, "it", "EUR"),    // Italy
    NL      ("nl",      3, "en", "EUR"),    // Netherlands
    UK      ("uk",      1, "en", "GBP"),    // UK
    US      ("us",      2, "en", "USD");    // USA
... getters / setters... }
```

In my API resource I have the following annotation

```
@GET
    @Path("/countries")
    @ApiOperation("Get countries")
    @CacheControl(maxAge = 1, maxAgeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
    @Override
    public List<CountryDto> getCountries(
            @QueryParam("websiteLocale") @ApiParam(required = true, defaultValue = "uk") final WebsiteLocale websiteLocale) {
        return delegate.getCountries(websiteLocale);
```

In the Swagger API test page for that endpoint it gives the accepted values as the Enum literals themselves

e.g. AU, CA, DE, ES, ES_US, EU, FR, FR_US

This breaks the controller (404 not found response) because it is looking for the associated string key for that enum

i.e. au, ca, de, es, es-us, eu, fr, fr-us

I had a look through swagger but could not see any specific annotation to look for a part of the enum properties.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just use a Simple String as type for websiteLocale, then try to fing the corresponding Enum Value for that supplied string manually inside your method? (And throw a WebApplicationException if an invalid value was supplied).

Comment: I guess you have to play with "allowableValues" of the ApiModelProperty. Not tested, just guessing :)